# Getting error after upgrading from Angular 8 to 12 - "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' "

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I had a fully functioning code in Angular 8. I decided to upgrade from 8 to Angular 12.

I have a dynamic reactive form. The form is of question answer format.
Based on who is login in the questions change. The answer is of Yes/No format. Based on who is login in and what answer option is chosen textbox dropdown and checkbox or all the there mentioned appreas.

Here is my code for the form

**Component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {      
    this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        questions: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.CreateForm();
}

get f() { return this.dynamicForm.controls; }
get t() { return this.f.questions as FormArray; }


CreateForm() {
    if (this.formdetail.questionList) {
        // CREATE Questions
        if (racialQues !==  this.formdetail.questionList[i].quetext && this.formdetail.questionList[i].quetext !== auditQues) {
            this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                quesIndex: [i + 1],
                ...
                controlName: [this.formdetail.questionList[i].selectedAns, [Validators.required]]
            }));
        } else if (this.formdetail.questionList[i].quetext === auditQues) {
            this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                quesIndex: [i + 1],
                ......
                selectedValue: [this.formdetail.auditTrail.selectedValue, this.reasonValidator],
            }));
        } else if (this.formdetail.questionList[i].quetext === racialQues) {
      
            this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({
                quesIndex: [i + 1],
                ......
                selectedAuxAns: [this.formdetail.questionList[i].val, [this.auxAnsValidator]]
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the html

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicForm"> 
<!--  Question Start -->
<div *ngFor="let ticket of t.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroup]="ticket" class="form-row">  
        <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="padding: .15em .5em">                                        
            <div class="input-group-prepend col-md-10" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">                
                <label class="input-group-text w-15">{{i + 1}}</label>
                <label class="input-group-text w-100" style="text-align: left; white-space: normal;">{{ticket.controls.name.value}}</label>
            </div>                                 
            <select formControlName="controlName" class="form-control col-md-2" style="height:auto !important;" 
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && ticket.controls.controlName.errors }"
                (change)="onChange($event.target.value, i)">
                <option [ngValue]="null"> --Select-- </option>
                <option *ngFor="let ansItem of formdetail.questionList[i].answerList" [ngValue]="ansItem" >{{ansItem.anstext}}</option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="submitted && ticket.controls.controlName.errors" class="invalid-feedback" style="height:auto !important;" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'input-group-append': submitted && ticket.controls.controlName.errors,
                         'col-md-1': submitted && ticket.controls.controlName.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="ticket.controls.controlName.errors.required">Required</div>
            </div>
            .
            .
            .
            .
            
        </div>  
    /div>
</div>     
<!--  Question End -->                
</form>
```

Now I am getting error in "ticket.control"

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

I am not sure why I am getting this error after upgrade.
I have tried `ticket.['control']` or `ticket.get('controlName')` as suggested by other article of similar error in stackoverflow but nothing works

Here is the snapshot of error

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `t` is of type `FormArray`, `FormArray.controls` array is of type [`AbstractControl[]`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1986), thus, each `ticket` at

```
<div *ngFor="let ticket of t.controls; let i = index">
```

line is of type `AbstractControl`, which does not have `controls` property as is seen in TS error in your screenshot. TS does not know that each `ticket` actually is of type `FormGroup` (set here `this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({...})` and which has [`controls` property](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1529)).

So you can try to add another getter `tControls`:

```
get f() { return this.dynamicForm.controls; }
get t() { return this.f.questions as FormArray; }
get tControls() { return this.t.controls as FormGroup[]; }
```

and use it within `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let ticket of tControls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroup]="ticket" class="form-row">
    ...
```

Please note, that now `[formGroup]` will also be properly filled with `FormGroup` and not `AbstarctControl`

One of your Angular upgrades probably added

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInputTypes": true,
}
```

to your `tsconfig.json` file, you can verify it just by setting these values to `false` and rebuilding your app, but I recommend to leave these strict checks.

Comment: Thank you @Andriy. I had tried this get tControls { return this.t.controls ; } and it was giving me the same error of Abstract control. Parsing was the key. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic answer (so generic code) to help fixing such an issue.
Let's suppose you have a loop through a field (call it elements) of type FormArray. This field is part of a form of type FormGroup

In your ts logic code (logic implementation) you should have something like:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
   //.. other fields
    elements: new FormArray([]),
  });
```

In your template (html file), you need to toop through the elements field:

```
<li
  *ngFor="let element of elements.controls">
  {{ element.value }}
</li>
```

In order to tell angular cli that elements has a property of controls (so of type FormArray), you need to format it in your ts logic code as the following (implement a getter for elements field):

```
  get elements() {
    return this.form.get('elements') as FormArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

'controls' isn't a [property of an AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl). instead you can use your form group, so 'dynamicForm.controls.controlName'

Comment: Do you have any example?